# How to prevent or disable deletion of array formula in a particular cell in the google sheet?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have an array formula in the particular cell. And I want to prevent / disable for accidentally deleting this array formula. I would like ask for advice on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, protect the range using Data/Protected Sheets & Ranges.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your assistance. Since I am the only user, what I did is "protect sheets and show warning" I would also like to learn the other method: how to make the absolutely protected.

Comment: There is no way to [protect against the owner of the sheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Chide-or-unhide-a-sheet%2Cedit-a-copy-of-a-protected-sheet%2Cprotect-a-range-or-sheet%2Cwho-can-protect-a-range-or-sheet). I think your solution will be the best approach.

Comment: Thank you for all the help John.